# Republishing Android App

Tags: android, google-play

I have published an android app from one account.
I want to republish that app from a different account by deleting the app from earlier account. Will the google play accept the republished app as the same app name has been used earlier.
While republishing i have renamed the app from **'AppName'** to **'App Name'**

Answer (score 1):

Name of the app is not used in identifying the apps. Play Store looks for the combination of the app's package name and developer signature.

> package_name + your_signature **must be different**

It can be:

1. Same signature, different package name
2. Different signature, different package name

You may use the existing signature in other accounts. As long as the above condition is met you may put any name for the app

Answer (score 1):

Like Marat said, it's not the name of an app that makes it unique. If you try to republish an app with the same package name and signature under a new account, Google will not allow it.

If you wish to publish your app on a different developer account though, you can transfer your app to your new account. It sounds like that would give you the result you're looking for. [Find more information about transferring your app to a new developer account here.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en)